# Удалить мусор из контента в div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошлые менеджеры сайта вставляли в контент новости горизонтальную черту в виде ______________________________________________________________ (более 60 символов), которая даже не попадает в абзац <р>.
Теперь нужно средствами jquery или javascript этот мусор убрать, так как он мешает мобильной версии сайта.

```html
<div class="ind_body">
...
_________________________________________________________________<br>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730309/find-all-text-nodes-in-html-page

```js
function textNodesUnder(node) {
  var all = [];
  for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) all.push(node);
    else all = all.concat(textNodesUnder(node));
  }
  return all;
}

var all = textNodesUnder(document.body);
all.forEach(e => e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.replace(/_/g, ""));
```

```html
<div class="ind_body">
  ... _________________________________________________________________
  <br> ...
</div>
```